# how to display an element next to an image without changing image position

Tags: html, css

I have an image map and when a user clicks on a tier I would like to display info next to it without the original image moving. See my two images below. The first is before I clicked on Tier4 and the 2nd is what is displayed after the click. I am trying to get the text to flow downward instead of across so the image is not moved.

[image]

[image]

```
<div style="display:flex;">
        <div id="tier4" style="display:none;">
            <div id="t4_functionality" style="border: solid 1px black;">
                <p>Executive level is focused on both tactical and strategic initiatives. They are responsible for running the business and improving it</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="tieredbrkdwn.jpg" alt="tieredbrkdwn" usemap="#workmap" style="display: flex;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 50%;">

        <map name="workmap">
            <area shape="poly" coords="380,30, 650,30, 650,190, 380,190" alt="tier4" onclick="tier4()">
            <area shape="poly" coords="280,200, 740,200, 740,320, 280,320" alt="tier3" onclick="tier3()">
            <area shape="poly" coords="160,321, 850,321, 850,465, 160,465" alt="tier2" onclick="tier2()">
            <area shape="poly" coords="20,470, 990,470, 990,660, 20,660" alt="tier1" onclick="tier1()">
        </map>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use visibility:hidden and visibility:visible on tier4, that div will stay in the layout and use up the space.

Comment: @Mifo this won't help as the element will still take space with `visibility: hidden;`, so the image will still not have its correct position

Comment: Please could you show us your CSS and also where are the texts to be vertically when they are clicked. Are they all to start in the same place or do they start opposite their own tier.

Comment: @AHaworth the CSS is inline. the text is positioned where I want it in the 2nd picture I just don't want the image to move. So the text should flow down instead of across the screen.

Comment: So just make it’s element 25% width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
        <div id="tier4" style="width:25%;visibility:hidden;">
            <div id="t4_functionality" style="border: solid 1px black;">
                <p>Executive level is focused on both tactical and strategic initiatives. They are responsible for running the business and improving it</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="tieredbrkdwn.jpg" alt="tieredbrkdwn" usemap="#workmap" style="display: flex;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 50%;">

        <map name="workmap">
            <area shape="poly" coords="380,30, 650,30, 650,190, 380,190" alt="tier4" onclick="tier4()">
            <area shape="poly" coords="280,200, 740,200, 740,320, 280,320" alt="tier3" onclick="tier3()">
            <area shape="poly" coords="160,321, 850,321, 850,465, 160,465" alt="tier2" onclick="tier2()">
            <area shape="poly" coords="20,470, 990,470, 990,660, 20,660" alt="tier1" onclick="tier1()">
        </map>
        <div style="width:25%;"></div>
        
    </div>
<script>
    function tier4() {
        const el = document.getElementById('tier4');
        el.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
```